# Mysql group by with normal column and mysql function aliases column

Tags: mysql, database

I have been trying to group by the mysql group by in normal column and mysql function aliases column where the mysql function aliases wont work group by 
The query i tried and which should work according to the mysql documentation.

```
SELECT `project`.`project_name`, SUM(cost_allocated) AS cost_allocated,
    count(task_id) as countTask, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.members SEPARATOR ';') AS members,     
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.indicators SEPARATOR ';') AS indicators, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.percent_complete SEPARATOR ';') AS percent_complete,
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.status SEPARATOR ';') AS status, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`task_registration`.`created_at`, '%M') AS month
FROM (`project`) 
INNER JOIN `task_registration` ON `task_registration`.`project` = `project`.`project_id` 
GROUP BY `task_registration`.`project`,`month` 
ORDER BY `project`.`project_id` desc
```

The result i get 
[image]

Now after removing the normal column group by and just adding mysql function aliases column it works fine but i need both

```
SELECT `project`.`project_name`, SUM(cost_allocated) AS cost_allocated, 
    count(task_id) as countTask, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.members SEPARATOR ';') AS members, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.indicators SEPARATOR ';') AS indicators, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.percent_complete SEPARATOR ';') AS percent_complete, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.status SEPARATOR ';') AS status, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`task_registration`.`created_at`, '%M') AS month
FROM (`project`) 
INNER JOIN `task_registration` ON `task_registration`.`project` = `project`.`project_id` 
GROUP BY `month` 
ORDER BY `project`.`project_id` desc
```

after removing `` task_registration`.`project `` from group by 
[image]

```
 GROUP BY `task_registration`.`project`,`month`  Doesnt work in this case
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18389/2 i have tried this so far

Comment: Please have a look now

Comment: What is the output you actually require? Both your result sets look to what I would expect

Comment: I need the result from up one and followed by group by month in 1st one there is no group by month 3-4 feb month in bot there one jan one feb

Comment: Can you mock up an example of the data you want (preferably with some test data that you would expect to generate that output)

Comment: i want to group by both 1st example group by projectname and 2nd example group by month so i want single query with both group by working

Comment: [use text instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/998537)

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to work out what you want without table declarations, sample input data and sample output data, but from your comment all I can suggest is using the 2nd query as a sub query and joining it to the results of the first query:-

```
SELECT project.project_name, 
    SUM(cost_allocated) AS cost_allocated,
    count(task_id) as countTask, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.members SEPARATOR ';') AS members,     
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.indicators SEPARATOR ';') AS indicators, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.percent_complete SEPARATOR ';') AS percent_complete,
    GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.status SEPARATOR ';') AS status, 
    DATE_FORMAT(task_registration.created_at, '%M') AS month,
    sub0.cost_allocated AS months_cost_allocated, 
    sub0.countTask AS months_countTask, 
    sub0.members AS months_members, 
    sub0.indicators AS months_indicators, 
    sub0.percent_complete AS months_percent_complete, 
    sub0.status AS months_status
FROM (`project`) 
INNER JOIN `task_registration` ON `task_registration`.`project` = `project`.`project_id` 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(task_registration.created_at, '%M') AS month,
        SUM(cost_allocated) AS cost_allocated, 
        COUNT(task_id) as countTask, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.members SEPARATOR ';') AS members, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.indicators SEPARATOR ';') AS indicators, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.percent_complete SEPARATOR ';') AS percent_complete, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(task_registration.status SEPARATOR ';') AS status
    FROM (project) 
    INNER JOIN task_registration ON task_registration.project = project.project_id
    GROUP BY `month` 
) sub0
ON DATE_FORMAT(task_registration.created_at, '%M') = sub0.`month`
GROUP BY task_registration.project,
        `month`, 
        months_cost_allocated, 
        sub0.countTask AS months_countTask, 
        sub0.members AS months_members, 
        sub0.indicators AS months_indicators, 
        sub0.percent_complete AS months_percent_complete, 
        sub0.status AS months_status
ORDER BY project.project_id desc
```

Comment: Why multiple group by month sub0? when i just need multiple column group by?

Comment: Because they are returned columns in effect, and in standard SQL any returned columns with a GROUP BY clause should be either aggregate columns or mentioned in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: And for that test data can you put out the exact results that you want (the actual results, not just an explanation of what you want), please

Comment: i want just two column of feb and jan only and grp concated of results

Comment: But Jan and Feb are rows. Please put example rows that you want output, not an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer i did it on my own

```
   SELECT COUNT( i.project_name ) AS completed_projects,i.month 
FROM (

SELECT `project`.`project_name` , SUM( cost_allocated ) AS cost_allocated, COUNT( task_id ) AS countTask, GROUP_CONCAT( task_registration.members
SEPARATOR  ';' ) AS members, GROUP_CONCAT( task_registration.indicators
SEPARATOR  ';' ) AS indicators, GROUP_CONCAT( task_registration.percent_complete
SEPARATOR  ';' ) AS percent_complete, GROUP_CONCAT( task_registration.status
SEPARATOR  ';' ) AS 
STATUS , DATE_FORMAT( task_registration.created_at,  '%M' ) AS 
MONTH FROM (
`project`
)
INNER JOIN  `task_registration` ON  `task_registration`.`project` =  `project`.`project_id` 
GROUP BY  `task_registration`.`project` 
ORDER BY  `project`.`project_id` DESC
) AS i
GROUP BY i.month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18389/11